# spring security in memory authentication accepts any password after first authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to add simple config for basic authentication using spring security `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`

After adding following configuration I am able to authenticate with the in memory user (myUser) and the password for this user:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
  }

  @Bean
  public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
    List<UserDetails> userDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    userDetailsList.add(User.withUsername("myUser").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
        .roles("USER").build());

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetailsList);
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
}
```

The thing is that if I change the password from postman I am still able to authenticate. If I stop application server and start the application again and try with wrong password and correct username it returns 401 ( which is expected). However if next request is sent with the correct header with username and password (myUser, password) and then send the request after that with wrong password it seems the wrong password is accepted. As soon as I change the username to some random word it returns 401 unauthorized. Something is missing from my configuration and I do not have a clue what is it.

Comment: There is nothing missing that is how BASIC authentication works. As soon as you are authenticated it will keep sending the correct username/password as a header. Next to that there is also state in the HTTP session which is also checked. If the username is the same it doesn't re-authenticate as it assumes it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring by default stores the HttpSession of the Authentication details. So whenever user logs in and authentication is successful, the details are stores in ThreadLocal and whenever the next login happens, it picks it up from the security context instead of authenticating again. Spring Security provides multiple Policies for Session Management. For your use case, you need to configure your HttpSecurity with SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS.

```
http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

You can also refer the below article for detailed information:
https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-session/